# Turning specific photoshop layers off as data is read from csv file

Tags: javascript, csv, photoshop

I am new to javascript and am trying to write a script for use in photoshop that reads data from a csv file.  The photoshop file has a variety of text layers that are fed data from the csv. I am having trouble turning off an image layer for every line of csv completed. Any ideas on how I could write this?

Here is the code so far:

```js
var data = [];
var dataFile = new File(app.activeDocument.path + '/data.csv');
dataFile.open('r');
dataFile.readln(); // Skip first line
while (!dataFile.eof) {
  var dataFileLine = dataFile.readln();
  var dataFilePieces = dataFileLine.split(',');
  data.push({
    art: dataFilePieces[0],
    tileNumber: dataFilePieces[0],
    tileCommon: dataFilePieces[1],
    tileSpecies: dataFilePieces[2],
    tileDescription: dataFilePieces[3],
    tileStatus: dataFilePieces[4],
  });
}
dataFile.close();


for (var tileIndex = 0; tileIndex < data.length; tileIndex++) {
  var tileData = data[tileIndex];

  //update number
  app.activeDocument.artLayers.getByName('Tile number').textItem.contents = tileData.tileNumber;

  //update common name
  app.activeDocument.artLayers.getByName('Common name').textItem.contents = tileData.tileCommon;

  //update species name
  app.activeDocument.artLayers.getByName('Species name').textItem.contents = tileData.tileSpecies;

  //update description
  app.activeDocument.artLayers.getByName('Description').textItem.contents = tileData.tileDescription;

  file = new File(app.activeDocument.path + '/' + tileData.tileCommon + '.png');
  opts = new ExportOptionsSaveForWeb();
  opts.format = SaveDocumentType.PNG;
  opts.PNG8 = false;
  opts.quality = 100;
  app.activeDocument.exportDocument(file, ExportType.SAVEFORWEB, opts);

}
confirm("All done!");
```

Comment: If it helps my intent is to turn off the upmost active layer [0] at the end of the script and selecting the next to have it ready for the next round, and then when the script complete again it will turn of the selected layer and move to the next, and so on.